# Clickable Website Banner

Tags: php, html, web

```
<div class="banner-base clearfix">
    <?php 

        $bannerImages   =   $objBanner->getFields("ban_image","position","learnlink");

        foreach($bannerImages as $banner) { ?>

            <div class="banner-item">
                <span class="banner-image">
                    <a href="<?php echo $banner['learnlink']; ?>">
                        <img src="img/banner-images/<?php echo $banner['ban_image']; ?>">
                    </a>
                </span>
            </div>
    <?php }?>
</div>
```

I am trying to make a website banner as clickable link, but it is not changing to a clickable banner.

Comment: is there any output for $banner[] at all?

Comment: <?php echo var_dump($bannerImages) ?> would help if you can add that please.

Comment: @Kitson88 FYI, you don't need to echo `var_dump()`. It returns void.

Comment: @jhmckimm So using echo var_dump() at the end of the file will not work? I'm not suggesting that he echo's the value from the foreach loop (`$banner`) but rather the function from his class which is initiliaised as `$bannerImages` and place that at the bottom of the file.

Comment: How I can solve this?

Comment: We need to work out if theres any data within the $bannerImages array. I've alredy suggested doing the following and placing at the end of your code above. `<?php echo var_dump($bannerImages); ?>`

Comment: @Kitson88 you don't need to echo the var_dump, `<?php var_dump($bannerImages); ?>` is enough.

Comment: @mtness thats fair enough. It's just force of habit which I suppose I should not be passing on. I'm still confused as to why it was suggested it returns void which is not the case....anyways...moving on :-)

Comment: Not solved. What to do now?

Comment: @NitheeshThomas: Maybe you should provide us with the additional info requested?!

Comment: see comments above: is there any output of $bannerImages at all? `<?php var_dump($bannerImages); ?>` at the end of the snippet will show you.

Comment: Nothing happening. What to do now?

Comment: What does the rendered HTML look like?

Answer (score 0):

Solved

```
$bannerImages   =   $objBanner->getFields("ban_image","position","learnlink");
```

I replaced the above line to below line

```
$bannerImages   =   $objBanner->getFields($table_fields,"","position");
```

And I added the on click event inside the div

```
<div class="banner-item" onclick="window.open('<?php echo $banner["learnlink"]; ?>'); return true;" style="cursor:pointer">
```